# How to select the text in the div using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hi everyone I am very new to selenium, just trying out one **scraper** for my project.
I want to select the text present in that div element which I have marked with red color.
I have tried using this:

```
driver.find_element(
        "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div"
    )
```

Please help me out, or suggest me a good tutorial.
Thanks a lot :)
[image: Please check the picture for more clarification about the page]

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(ELEMENT_XPATH).text
```

Use XPath not Full XPath

Answer (score 1):

Try to find Relative xpath. The xapth for that element would be:

```
//div[contains(@class,'valueValue')]
Or
//div[starts-with(@class,'valueValue')]
```

To extract the text from that element:

```
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'valueValue')]")
value = data.text
# Or
value = data.get_attribute('innerText')
```

Links to refer - [Link1](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/), [Link2](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html)